# Executing python scripts with subprocess.call using shebang

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, shebang

I'm writing a (somewhat) modular application in Python 3 and I'd like to run arbitrary programs from it, said program being specified at runtime and not necessarily a python script.

So I use for example,

```
subprocess.call([spam, "-i", eggs, "-o", ham])
```

If `spam` is a python script, with shebang to `python3` and executable rights, I get

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

if I

```
subprocess.call(["python3", spam, "-i", eggs, "-o", ham])
```

it works fine.

Do you know why? How can I run `spam` without specifying `python3`?

Comment: Is the python script file executable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `shell=True`, and you need your array to be turned into a command string, like this:

```
subprocess.call(' '.join([spam, "-i", eggs, "-o", ham]), shell=True)
```

This will invoke the shell instead of the direct command, and the shell should be able to handle the shebang.

Comment: Nice, it works :) Do you know why `call` doesn't mind the shebang?

Comment: Rectification : to pass the arguments to `spam` one need to write `subprocess.call(" ".join([spam, "-i", eggs, "-o", ham]), shell=True)
` or the arguments will be passed to the shell, not to the script. See http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: @Evpok: excellent call, I didn't even notice that. I'll update it.

Comment: And no I'm afraid I don't know why subprocess by itself doesn't seem to be able to execute a script starting with a shebang.

Comment: Wikipedia says execve should handle it, and I checked in the source, that is what is used, so either Wikipedia is wrong, or there is something strange going on.

Comment: It's better to use `shutil.which()` to find the executable than to use `shell=True`, so that way you don't have to worry about escaping/quoting the arguments, and then it's platform independent.

Comment: Although, I just tested in my dev, and calling a shebang script that is executable using subprocess works fine in my Linux without using `shell=True`, so I don't know why it doesn't work for @evpok.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
subprocess.call(['spam.py', "-i", eggs, "-o", ham])
```

Comment: It's `spam`, not `"spam"` : a variable and not a string. Direct reference to the script as you suggest don't work either.

Comment: This post is not useful as it doesn't answer the original question. The answer is stated above which is to use `shell=True`.