# Python raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python

I have to move a python script from a server that use Python 2.6 to another on that uses 2.4.

I had to make some modifications. now im stuck. i keep on getting this error

```
 File "subprocess.py", line 975, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

my log ouput:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/cnfs/dev/regions/que/cli/rpntrans_requests/scripts/0.6a/process.py", line 281, in ?
process(filename)
File "/cnfs/dev/regions/que/cli/rpntrans_requests/scripts/0.6a/process.py", line 259, in process
outputs = transformations[tr.tag](file).execute()
File "/cnfs/dev/regions/que/cli/rpntrans_requests/scripts/0.6a/process.py", line 114, in execute
t.execute()
File "/cnfs/dev/regions/que/cli/rpntrans/current/rpntrans.py", line 113, in execute
last_step.execute()
File "/cnfs/dev/regions/que/cli/rpntrans/current/rpntrans.py", line 941, in execute
stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr
File "subprocess.py", line 413, in call
return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
File "subprocess.py", line 543, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "subprocess.py", line 975, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

code from rpntrans.py

```
    subprocess.call([
        os.path.join(module_root, 'bin/fst2r2c'),
        file,
        v_name, 
        str(r.ip2), str(r.ip2),
        out_file,
        '1', '0',
        '%s (ip1:%i)' % (self.dict[v_name]["desc"], r.ip1),
        self.dict[v_name]["units"],
        self.format,
        self.__get_interpolation(v_name)
    ],
        stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr
    )
```

anyhone have an idea ?

thank you

Comment: Try using `shell=True`. And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441507/executing-python-scripts-with-subprocess-call-using-shebang.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `bin/fst2r2c` is a binary executable, is it the right format for the new server?  (Have you moved from Linux to BSD, or 32-bit to 64-bit?)

If `bin/fst2r2c` is a script, is its `#!` line intact?  (Have you edited it on Windows and introduced a `\r`?  Is the pathname of its executable different on the new machine, eg. `/usr/bin` vs. `/usr/local/bin`?)

Comment: yes fst2r2c is a binary executable. I fixed the problem. I had to recompile fst2r2c on the new server. thank you for the hint!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Run the command you want to call from `subprocess` from the command line first and see if it works. Than print out the command you generate with Python, i.e. `os.path.join(module_root, 'bin/fst2r2c')` and see if looks the same.